# need to fix slideshow and figure out responsiveness. only CSS/HTML

Tags: css, responsive-design

The image is cut off a bit and the text to the left isn’t centering also I tried to add a min-height to the pics and max-width to banner image for responsiveness but they didn’t take. any tips on these?

[image: pics of website and code]

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Comfortaa', cursive;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

h1 {
  font-family: 'Righteous', cursive;
  font-size: 4rem;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}

header {
  height: 8vh;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.nav-links {
  height: 8vh;
  width: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}

.nav-link:hover {
  border-bottom: 4px black solid;
}

.banner {
  background-image: url(/Aleesha/woman\ wit\ hat.jpg);
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30vh;
  margin-bottom: 2vh;
}

.hats {
  display: flex;
  height: 40vh;
}

.hat-text {
  border: 2px dotted;
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
}

h2 {
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px dotted;
  font-size: 8rem;
  align-items: center;
}

#slider {
  flex: 1.8;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#slider figure {
  position: relative;
  width: 500%;
  margin: 0;
  left: 0;
  animation: 20s slider infinite;
}

#slider figure img {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  max-width: 20%;
  min-height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}

@keyframes slider {
  0% {
    left: 0;
  }
  20% {
    left: 0;
  }
  25% {
    left: -100%;
  }
  45% {
    left: -100%;
  }
  50% {
    left: -200%;
  }
  70% {
    left: -200%;
  }
  75% {
    left: -300%;
  }
  95% {
    left: -300%;
  }
  100% {
    left: -400%;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <main>
    <!--BANNER-->
    <section class="banner">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="banner-content">
          <h1>ALEESHA</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <!--HATS-->
    <section class="hats">
      <div class="hat-text">
        <H2>HATS</H2>
      </div>
      <div id="slider">
        <figure>
          <img src="/Aleesha/Pics/Slideshow/Hats/slide1.jpg" alt="Black Reptile Hat">
          <img src="/Aleesha/Pics/Slideshow/Hats/slide2.jpg" alt="Cheeta Squence Hat">
          <img src="/Aleesha/Pics/Slideshow/Hats/slide3.jpg" alt="White Thug Life Bucket Hat">
          <img src="/Aleesha/Pics/Slideshow/Hats/slide4.jpg" alt="yellow W worn blue hat">
          <img src="/Aleesha/Pics/Slideshow/Hats/slide1.jpg" alt="Life is Fantastic yellow hat">
        </figure>
      </div>
    </section>
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: add code here, not as an image

Comment: hey sorry about that. i just added it

Comment: Thanks to Alon Eitan for the formatting assist!